# Excessive resource usage: memcached Linux Centos 7

Tags: java, linux, memory, centos, cwp

This is an email I get every few hours from my Centos Machine for Mencached.
But it is not only for that service - also for the Java Apps I am running too

What could be causing Excessive Resource Usage

```
Time:         Sun Oct 18 12:00:36 2020 +0100
Account:      memcached
Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     441265 > 1800 (seconds)
Executable:   /usr/bin/memcached
Command Line: /usr/bin/memcached -u memcached -p 11211 -m 64 -c 1024
PID:          391 (Parent PID:391)
Killed:       No
```

and

```
Account:      appserver
Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     231741 > 1800 (seconds)
Executable:   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java
Command Line: java -DWORootDirectory=/opt -DWOLocalRootDirectory=/opt/Local -DWOUserDirectory=/ -DWOEnvClassPath= -DWOApplicationClass=com.webobjects.monitor.wotaskd.Application -DWOPlatform=UNIX -Dcom.webobjects.pid=9004 -classpath WOBootstrap.jar com.webobjects._bootstrap.WOBootstrap -WOPort xxxx -er.wotaskd.sshd.enabled true
PID:          9004 (Parent PID:9004)
Killed:       No
```

Answer (score 0):

Memcached runs all the time you need to set your csf firewall to ignore
add
exe:/usr/sbin/memcached
to your csf pignore

You could try editing this in pignore, save and restart LFD, and see what happens

If you still receiving the email notifications form lfd just change exe:/usr/sbin/memcached to exe:/usr/bin/memcached and try again and don't forget to save and restart LFD.

Comment: Edit LFD ignore file in the GUI
/etc/csf/csf.pignore via CLI